# Get fields out of an entity returned by EntityFieldQuery

Tags: 7, database

I have a video content type. I run the following query in `hook_cron`:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node');
$query->entityCondition('bundle', 'video');
$query->propertyCondition('status', 1);
$results = $query->execute();
```

This returns number of entity object with property `nid`, `vid` and `type`. I want to use this object to find a value of a particular field of the video (say duration). I don't want to use `node_load`, because I would have done that in the first place instead of using the query. How can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [EntityFieldQuery Extra Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/efq_extra_field) module could solve your problem.

The query, as show below, will return an object that contains the entity id, entity type, and an object that contains entity_type, entity_id, revision_id, bundle, and the requested field.  Your code would be:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQueryExtraFields();

$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'video')
  ->addExtraField('field_duration', 'value', 'value')
  ->propertyCondition('status', 1);

$results = $query->execute();
```

I am currently using this solution on a site.

Answer (score 11):

It can't - an `EntityFieldQuery` will only ever load the entity ID, and the bundle keys.

There's no choice but to use `node_load_multiple()` (or the equivalent if using a different entity type).

```
$nodes = node_load_multiple(array_keys($results['node']));
```

Bear in mind that the `$conditions` parameter of `node_load_multiple()` is deprecated; in favour of `EntityFieldQuery` as I understand it.

You could theoretically subclass `EntityFieldQuery` and override the `execute()` method to return the fully loaded entities - but you'll also need to extend the class so it always knows what entity type it's querying for; otherwise it won't know which key to use in `$results`.

Comment: Thank you. Just a minor doubt. I didn't get when you say "subclass `EntityFieldQuery` - but you'll _also_ need to extend the class". Isn't creating a subclass not the same as extending one? Or are you referring to something else I'm not understanding?

Comment: Sorry, poor choice of words. I just meant you'll have to equip your subclass to unconditionally accept an entity type argument, as it'll be required to load the entity objects